Mounting Error After Upgrading From 22.04 to 24.04
I got error from accessing drive partition. Unable to access location
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/dell/F89E56AB9E566264: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Recently i upgrade from 22 to 24.How do I solve this error? Please help me

This question is similar to: Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
